# MouseWheel event doesn't fire on a non-Selectable Control

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, mousewheel

I have written a custom Control, based on other code, which includes a call to `SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);`

This prevents the following code from being called (which works if I remove the above line and click on the Control first to 'focus' it):

```
    protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollBar.Value = Math.Min(ScrollBar.Value - e.Delta, ScrollBar.Maximum - ScrollBar.LargeChange);

        LayoutChanged();
    }
```

My control does not need focus so `Selectable=false` is correct.

### What do I need to do so that I can run this code whenever the mouse is over my control and the MouseWheel is moved regardless of where the focus is?

Thanks for the comments. A additional info:-

- I am running Windows 7 but any solution must work on any OS.
- The Control is inherited via Control/ControlBase/BaseControl/BaseStyleControl where the latter 3 are DevExpress controls.
- The real focus should not be changed just because the cursor hovers over my control
- There are no child controls other than a scrollbar (an inherited DevExpress one) which is normally invisible and shows itself when the mouse hovers over where it would be when visible.
- The control does nothing but draw itself (imagine a number of bookshelves one under the other with book covers drawn on them - the number of shelves increases to accommodate all the books and the scrollbar allows all to be scrolled into view.
- Since this is a use-anywhere Control, getting MouseWheel events from a Parent that knows about its requirements isn't a good idea.
- Maybe there is a way of registering for a first-look (is that a MessagePreview?) to pinch MouseWheel events before normal processing happens.

Comment: Are you inheriting directly from `Control`, or subclassing something more complex like a `Panel`?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Here (on a Panel subclass) the wheel event is always triggered.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this either, not on a `UserControl`, and not on a custom control that inherits from `Panel`. **Edit:** Actually, not even on a class that directly inherits from `Control`!

Comment: then there probably is logic suppressing event propagation depending on the control style flagset, somewhere in that "...on other code..."

Comment: TaW cannot reproduce this because it depends on the Windows version.  Win10 has new behavior, it sends the MouseWheel notification to the control that is being hovered.  Previous Windows versions sent it to the control that has the focus.  So you are no doubt "previous", fixing it is not exactly simple.  The control with focus, whatever it might be, has to forward the message to this control.  You'd be lucky if it is a control inside the user control.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/eb922ed2-1036-41ca-bd15-49daed7b637c/outlookstyle-wheel-mouse-behavior?forum=winforms

Comment: Hans' article might prove useful as all my apps have a global handler for PreFilterMessage anyway. If I listen for MouseWheel events there and then check if the Control under the Mouse Cursor implements a specific new interface, sayIMouseWheelHandler, then I should be able to implement an OS and parent independent solution.

Comment: Han's article did provide the solution! Hans, do you want to create a proper Answer about using a PreFilterMessage so it can be credited accordingly?

Comment: Wow! I was actually testing on Win7 _but_ I have a [software/tool](https://stefansundin.github.io/altdrag/) that allows scrolling inactive windows _(like the Win10 feature)_ and I completely forgot about that! As always, @Hans gets to the bottom of everything :D